# Poperty of EasingMode is not apper in Properties of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

## Description

If you declare a public property of **EasingMode** for your **UserControl** then it's not shown in Properties of Visual Studio.
This is a strange behavior just for **EasingMode** not for other custom properties.

## Problem

If you have a property of **EasingMode**, It's usable in XAML and it's valid property. But i need to have access to this property from **Properties** in **Visual Studio**.
A simple public property from simple enum must accesible in design-time like other but it's not work for **EasingMode**, Just for **EasingMode**

## Quistion

I know that i can change the value of property from code or XAML directly, But

1. I need to find out a WHY this property has this strange behaviour.
2. How to fix this? What's solution to show a property of this enum
   comes to **properties** panel in Design Time in Visual Studio?

## Example

look at this example

```cs
[Bindable(true)]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("TEST")]
public EasingMode A1
{
    get { return (EasingMode)this.GetValue(A1Property); }
    set { this.SetValue(A1Property, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty A1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("A1", typeof(EasingMode), typeof(UserControl1));

[Bindable(true)]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("TEST")]
public MessageBoxButton A2
{
    get { return (MessageBoxButton)this.GetValue(A2Property); }
    set { this.SetValue(A2Property, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty A2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("A2", typeof(MessageBoxButton), typeof(UserControl1));
```

A1 and A2 are simple properties from simple enums but the A1 is not coming to **Properties** Panel of **Visual Studio**. Test it and find it out and help me :)

[image: Screen Shot]

- [Test Project Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7mkowqhbznl6kg/201309021747.test_project.rar)
- [Screen Shot Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi9vut3otoia0df/201309021747ss01.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to see the properties of your `UserControl` in the Visual Studio designer? If this is correct, please take a look at the [Design-Time Attributes for Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx) page at MSDN.

There you will find a number of useful attributes that you can define on your properties:

```
[Category("Alignment"), Description("Specifies the alignment of text.")]
public ContentAlignment TextAlignment { //... }
```

> From MSDN.

UPDATE >>>

Sorry, I didn't quite understand you properly before. However, now that I do and that I have tested your problem, I can tell you that *your* code *does* work:

[image]

You will just need to build your project before the designer can update itself.

Comment: No, i can see my all custom properties. If you read it again please and test this part of source code then you can find it ... Just the A1 property is not shown. If you declare a property of EasingMode then it's disappear from properties in design-time. Please test it and try to help me :)

Comment: I really thanks but i test it again and again and i have no chance for find the wrong point. i share my test project here and i'll be grateful if you could possible share your test project. See these [PROJECT Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7mkowqhbznl6kg/201309021747.test_project.rar) and [SS Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi9vut3otoia0df/201309021747ss01.png)

Comment: I just added *your* code into my project. At first, the property did not appear, but then I selected `Build Solution` in Visual Studio and then it appeared. I can't share this project as it is a work application.

Comment: Ok, i shared my project with you. would you please just a test it:), As you can see it's not appear. Is your project a **WPF project**?

Comment: Sorry, I only have VS2010 so I can't open your project... maybe an issue with VS2012? And yes, my project is a WPF project.

Comment: Open just the project (the csproj file and leave the solution), It works with VS2010 too and test it, please, We can find it :)

Comment: There was only a project there and it wouldn't open in my version of VS2010. I tried to 'open existing project' and VS said no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to put Browsable Attribute on your property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Oops, No. The `[Browsable(true)]` not works in this case, test it :) it's really a wierd.